# VBA ColorIndex - colors changed?

Tags: excel, vba, colors

After running following script (VBA Excel) in my current workbook, I'm getting different colors compare to standard ColorIndex palette.

```
Sub colors()

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 56
    With Cells(i, "A")
        .Interior.ColorIndex = i
        .Value = i
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

ColorIndex Colors - current Workbook (wrong)

[image]

If I open a new workbook and run script, I am getting standard colors.

ColorIndex Colors - NEW Workbook (correct)

[image]

What could be wrong? 
Is it possible to change ColorIndex vs colors (rewrite internal excel color palette) ?

Comment: What is the theme in your workbook vs new workbook (default theme)?

Comment: Both are "Office".

Comment: If you want constant colors across all machines, use `Color(RGB)` property instead.  `Colorindex` may vary from machine to machine depending on the palette. Do an internet search for `Color` vs `ColorIndex` for more info.